# Pre-Staging Data Solution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tasked with replacing a costly stored procedure which performs calculations across 10 - 15 tables, some of which contain many millions of rows. The plan is to pre-stage the many computations and store the results in separate tables for speeding reading.

Having quickly created these new tables and inserted all of the necessary pre-staged data as a test case, the execution time of getting the same results is vastly improved, as you would expect.

My question is, **what is the best practice for keeping these new separate tables up to date**?

- A procedure which runs at a specific interval could do it, but there
  is a requirement for the data to be live.
- A trigger on each table could do it, but that seems very costly, and
  could cause slow-downs for everywhere else that uses these tables.

Are there other alternatives?

Comment: The best approach depends on the user requirements for accessing the data.  Strangers can't really answer that question.

Comment: I've tried to explain these without making my question too localised, perhaps SO is the wrong place for this issue?

Comment: Have you considered indexed views?

Comment: @RichBenner Hadn't heard of them to be honest, looks like a possibility, and worth a test, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yeah, they're pretty useful in the right circumstance. I've just had to apply one locally which dramatically reduced some select statements. The only issue is that it has to recalculate when the underlying tables are modified (inserts, updates, deletes). You also won't be able to modify the underlying table schema as you'll need schema binding switched on. you can drop the index, do what you need to do, then reapply it if you need to go down that route.

Comment: @RichBenner Would you mind putting that together in an answer, it's a good suggestion for this kind of issue that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered Indexed Views for this? As long as you meet the criteria for creating Indexed Views (no self joins etc) it may well be a good solution.

The downsides of Indexed Views are that when the data in underlying tables is changed (delete, update, insert) then it will have to recalculate the indexed view. This can slow down these types of operations in certain circumstances so you have to be careful. I've put some links to documentation below;

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-indexed-views/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191432.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

what is the best practice for keeping these new separate tables up to date?

Answer is it depends .Depends on what ..?

1.How frequently you will use those computed values
2.what is the acceptable data latency

we to have same kind of reporting where we store computed values in seperate tables and use them in reports.In our case we run this sps before sending the reports through SQL server agent

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an A/B table solution.  Place a generic view on over the _A table version (CREATE VIEW MY_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_A).  And then you rebuild the _B version, and then switch the view to the _B version (CREATE VIEW MY_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_B).  It takes twice as much space for processing, but it gives you the opportunity to build your tables without down-time.